# Does JavaScript's typeof function check for null

Tags: javascript

Does javascripts `typeof` expression check for null?

```
var test = {};
console.log(typeof test['test']);//"undefined"

var test = null;
console.log(typeof test['test']);//TypeError: test is null
```

Obviously, but why the error, if `typeof null` is an object?

EDIT:
I know how to avoid the type error, and that `null` has no properties, but I'm wondering is there an explanation to the behavior of `typeof`.

Comment: because the first test is null

Comment: `null` has no "test" member, attempting to accessing it is illegal

Comment: the issue is you're trying to read the val of `null['test']`

Comment: You can check the typeof null, but you can't access a property of null, as null has no properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var test = { test: null };
console.log(typeof test['test']);// will be object
```

Your code throws exception because you are reading property of null like this:

```
null['test']
```

Comment: In fact, you could have a line that just says: "test['test'];" (no actual action with the value) and it would still throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to access an element of `test`, but `test` is `null` and NOT an array/object. So the following code throws an error: `test['test']`.

The `typeof` would work fine if you passed it `null` directly. For example, using the  node.js console:

```
> typeof null
'object'
```

Answer (score 0):

you're asking it to read the property "test" of null which makes no sense, the error is basically telling you "test is null -> can not read property "test" of null".

you should just be doing `typeof test` instead of `typeof test['test']`, I'm not sure why you're doing it the latter way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try you test as

```
typeof (test && test['test'])
```

this way you avoid TypeError